# Infer prop types of generic children React components with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to force TypeScript to correctly type-check the generic hierarchy of React components like this ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=72#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdBArgHb7AQuYQQwA8AFQw8YAPgAUAbzi4AFsAA2AE0pcAvgC440uYpVYWW7HhgA6Y-gCiCrCAP9JYZDFlbxADy1CRASjgBeUThUGChgFgBzNSC1P0k6OES4ShgmKC5dZVV6NQZmNhgOLgEsd34BCWknFzhNbWrXOA8vP0Dg0PCouISklLSuPiVgADdRR2dZNT4AeiHRnIZwmCwoAjwsOAARGAhtHsTh5AUmLC0QsMiFulLIWBlOELgAYRJIFnsAuD5hXj5tiFEokEpXgDX8kncASC7lMh2OWDUcGmQOmPzEQA) link):

```js
import * as React from "react";

function Root<TRoot>({ children }: { children: React.ReactElement<{path: (x: TRoot) => string}> }) {
    return children;
}

function Text<T>({ path }: {path: (x: T) => string}) {
    return <div>{path}</div>;
}

interface Dto {
    value: string;
}

// Error: Object is of type 'unknown' (because TypeScript can't infer type of Text function)
export const Component = <Root<Dto>><Text path={x => x.value} /></Root>
```

In this simple example easy way to solve the problem is to manually add type information to the `Text` component:

```
export const Component = <Root<Dto>><Text<Dto> path={x => x.value} /></Root>
```

But in real life React tree is more complicated and I want automatic type inference.

Are there any ways to approach this and help TypeScript to correctly infer all types in the tree? Now I only have an idea to write a babel plugin that will add the type information to the JSX elements. But I don't like this solution, because plugin code can be tricky and also in this case I will need a Language Service plugin to enable autocompletion for `path` prop in the IDE.

Comment: This is a tough one.  `Text<T>` returns a `JSX.Element` with no knowledge of what `T` value was used to generate that element.  The `ReactElement` type has generics, but in practice they don't really matter because it's just JSX regardless.  Typescript doesn't really "play nicely" with React children for those and other reasons.  My recommendation is to rewrite this in a way that uses props instead of `children`. You can pass an array of child generating objects where one property is the render function and other property contains the child's props.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, yes, I understand that this is a tough case for TypeScript. I also thought about replacing the default `React.createElement` factory with another factory with more typings in it (this factory can emit some plain objects with precise typings and after that we can emit React tree from this representation). But at the moment I don't understand how this can be done.